# Converting Python regex to VisualBasic

Tags: python, regex, vb.net

I'm converting a python application to VB.net and I need help with this regular expression:

```
a = 'abcdef'
b = re.compile('[' + a + ']{3,}$', re.I)
```

Is it possible to convert it to Visual Basic, if so, can you provide any code?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a legitimate question (although the solution *could* have been found with Googling, but then the same is true for almost all questions here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim b As New Regex("[" + a + "]{3,}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

I fail to see the problem, though.